# Tag merge and synonym request: [glass-onion] → [glass-onion-a-knives-out-mystery]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Since the full and official title of the movie is *Glass Onion: A Knives Out Mystery* (according to Netflix, IMDb, and Rotten Tomatoes), I am requesting that [glass-onion](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/glass-onion) be merged and synonymized to [glass-onion-a-knives-out-mystery](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/glass-onion-a-knives-out-mystery), so that the tag will reflect the movie's official title.

Comment: @AnkitSharma It seems that the tags were merged but not synonymized.

Comment: Making synonym added no extra values as both tag had "glass onion" in them in start. Also unused tag auto delete after some time so nothing to worry.

Comment: @AnkitSharma There are no downsides to adding the synonym and a user might inadvertently re-use or recreate [[tag:glass-onion]] in the future.

Comment: If they type glass-o they will get this suggestion only and if someone creates the wrong tag mods can fix it quickly.